# Plotting two variables using ggplot2 - same x axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have two graphs with the same x axis - the range of x is 0-5 in both of them.
I would like to combine both of them to one graph and I didn't find a previous example.
Here is what I got:

```
c <- ggplot(survey, aes(often_post,often_privacy)) + stat_smooth(method="loess")
c <- ggplot(survey, aes(frequent_read,often_privacy)) + stat_smooth(method="loess")
```

How can I combine them?
The y axis is "often privacy" and in each graph the x axis is "often post" or "frequent read". 
I thought I can combine them easily (somehow) because the range is 0-5 in both of them.

Many thanks!

Comment: This is pretty easy by reshaping (`reshape2::melt`) and then using an aesthetic such as colour (or simply group) to distinguish the two variables.  You need to `melt` in such a way that you keep `often_privacy` as an id variable. If you post a small subset of your data (with `dput`) I'm sure you'll get an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `+` to combine other plots on the same `ggplot` object. For example, to plot points and smoothed lines for both pairs of columns:

```
ggplot(survey, aes(often_post,often_privacy)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_smooth() + 
geom_point(aes(frequent_read,often_privacy)) + 
geom_smooth(aes(frequent_read,often_privacy))
```

Comment: this answers the question nicely, although I think my comment above suggests the more 'idiomatic' way to do it (which among other things provides (1) an automatic legend (2) more compact code [although for only two variables there's not a big advantage])

Answer (score 10):

Example code for Ben's solution.

```
#Sample data
survey <- data.frame(
  often_post = runif(10, 0, 5), 
  frequent_read = 5 * rbeta(10, 1, 1), 
  often_privacy = sample(10, replace = TRUE)
)
#Reshape the data frame
survey2 <- melt(survey, measure.vars = c("often_post", "frequent_read"))
#Plot using colour as an aesthetic to distinguish lines
(p <- ggplot(survey2, aes(value, often_privacy, colour = variable)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df <- data.frame(x=x_var, y=y1_var, type='y1') 
df <- rbind(df, data.frame(x=x_var, y=y2_var, type='y2'))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group=type, col=type)) + geom_line()
```

[image]