# How to visualize two column in bar chart using R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I don't know if my question clear enough...

I have this table

```
  Name              Mark_Oral    Mark_Written   Total_M_Oral Total_M_Written
1 Hercule Poirot        50           49              858          781
2     Joe O'Neil        70           79             1056         1083
3   John McAuley        81           99             1219         1333
```

and I have to visualize the last two column in bar chart using R to compare student total mark

Data

```
table <- structure(list(Name = c("Hercule Poirot", "Joe O'Neil", "John McAuley"),
                        Mark_Oral = c(50L, 70L, 81L),
                        Mark_Written = c(49L, 79L, 99L),
                        Total_M_Oral = c(858L, 1056L, 1219L),
                        Total_M_Written = c(781L, 1083L, 1333L)),
                   .Names = c("Name", "Mark_Oral", "Mark_Written", "Total_M_Oral", "Total_M_Written"),
                   row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: is that a table or matrix? `barplot(table[, 3:4])` or a data frame? please `dput(table)` and add to your question

Comment: sorry I am new to R ... Its a data frame

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting two variables using ggplot2 - same x axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242420/plotting-two-variables-using-ggplot2-same-x-axis)

Answer (score 0):

With ggplot2 (as your tags suggest) the syntax is:

```
 ggplot(data = table,aes(x= Total_M_Oral,y=Total_M_Written))+geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Where table is replaced by the name of your dataframe.

### Edit

I was unsure that my first answer really answered your question (multiple uses of bars).

**Create dummy data**

```
df<-data.frame(x = rpois(n = 100,lambda = 800),y = rpois(n = 100,lambda = 800))
```

**With previous plot:**

[image: ggplot(data = df,aes(x= x,y=y))+geom_bar(stat = "identity")]

**If you want to count and have a color for Oral and one for written**

```
df2<-data.frame(x = c(df$x,df$y),y = rep(c("written","oral"),each = nrow(df)))

ggplot(data = df2,aes(x= x,fill=y),alpha = I(0.5))+geom_bar(stat = "count")
```

Which gives:

[image: barplot oral/written]

Comment: alpha parameter is not necessary, it just deals with the transparency so that you can see when there are overlapping bars.

### With student names

```
df3<-data.frame(name = rep(table$Name,times = 2),
                        y = c(table$Total_M_Oral, table$Total_M_Written),
                        fill = rep(c("oral","written"),each = nrow(table)))
ggplot(data = df3, aes(x = name,y= y,fill = fill,alpha = 0.5))+geom_bar(stat= "identity")
```

[image: bars with names]

Comment: This will put one of them in X and the other in Y , While I want to put both of them in X to compare student results in Written & Oral

Comment: This is what I thought, I was editing my answer for that. The second code may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks ... but how can I make the student name appear in the X instead of the numbers ... so it visualize each student name and his oral an written marks ...

Comment: @Sara `ggplot(reshape2::melt(table[, c(1,4:5)], id.vars = 'Name'), aes(Name, value, fill = variable)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Comment: @Sara the third version should do what you want.

Comment: @rawr this was an issue of formatting. It was supposed to display the first graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can use + to combine other plots on the same ggplot object. For example:

```
ggplot(survey, aes(often_post,often_privacy)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_smooth() + 
geom_point(aes(frequent_read,often_privacy)) + 
geom_smooth(aes(frequent_read,often_privacy))
```